# Проверка были ли изменения в Edit

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Цель следующая, у нас имеется форма, в обработчике OnClose этой формы нужно написать код, проверяющий, были ли внесенный изменения в текст компонента Edit1. Если были, то сделать видимой вторую форму, если не были, то закрыть первую форму.
Нашел решение, но при помощи переменной, оно не подходит в том случае, если у нас несколько Edit.
вот то чего я добился:

```
var 
  Form1: TForm1; 
  k:integer;

implementation

uses Unit2;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
k:=1; 
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction); 
begin 
if k=1 then form2.ShowModal; 
end; 
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

попробуй через Tag это делать. 
тут уж можешь для каждого Едита менять тэг отдельно:

```
 procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
 begin
  if TEdit(Sender).Tag = 0 then
   TEdit(Sender).Tag:= 1;
 end;
```

А потом каждый Едит проверять при закрытии формы.

Или вообще менять тэг самой формы и при закрытии его проверять.

```
 procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
 begin
  if selt.tag = 0 then
    self.Tag = 1;
 end;

 procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
 begin
   CanClose:= False;
   if self.Tag = 0 then
     CanClose:= True
   else
     Form2.ShowModal;
 end;
```